# c threads and resource locking

Tags: c, multithreading, resources, mutex, locks

I have a 2 dimensional array and 8 concurrent threads writing to the array. If each thread reads/writes to a different array, will it result in a seg fault?

For example:

```
char **buffer;
//each thread has its own thread ID
void set(short ID, short elem, char var)
{
     buffer[ID][elem] = var;
}
```

Would this be ok? I know this is pseudocode-ish, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each thread writes to a different sub-array, this aspect of your code will be fine and you will not need locking.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple threads reading or writing to memory does not, by itself, lead to seg faults. What it can do is result in a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), where the results depend indeterminately on the ordering of operations of the multiple threads. The consequences depend on what you do with the memory you read ... if you read a value and then use it as an index or dereference a pointer, that might result in an out of bounds access even though the logic of the code if run by just one thread could not.

In your specific case, if each thread writes to non-overlapping memory because it uses a different ID, there's no possibility of a race condition when accessing the array. However, there could be a race condition when *assigning the ID*, resulting in two threads receiving the same ID ... so you need to use a lock or other way of guaranteeing that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you will need to be careful of is how or when the 2D array is allocated. If all allocation occurs before the worker threads begin to access the array(s), and each worker thread reads and writes to only one of the "rows" of the master array for the lifetime of the thread, and it is the only thread to access that row, then you should not have any threading issues accessing or updating entries in the arrays.

If only one thread is writing to a row, but multiple threads could be reading from that same row, then you may need to work out some synchronization plan or else your readers may occasionally see inconsistent / incoherent data due to partial writes by a concurrent writer.

If each worker thread is hard-bound to a single "row" in the master array, it's also possible to allocate and reallocate the memory needed for each row by the worker thread itself, including updating the slot in the main array to point to the row data (re)allocated by the thread. There should be no contention for the pointer slot in the main array because only this worker thread is interested in that slot. Make sure the master array is allocated before any worker threads get started. For this scenario, also make sure that your C RTL malloc implementation is thread safe. (you may have to select a thread-safe RTL in your build options)